# how to set GROUP_CONCAT in query in yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2, group-concat

I want to put follow query :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`user_id` SEPARATOR ',') FROM `damages` WHERE `server_id`=2
```

in my main query:

```
$q = new Query();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Ticket::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
            ->andWhere(['in', 'user_id', [$q->select(["GROUP_CONCAT(`user_id` SEPARATOR ',')"])->from('damages')->where(['server_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])]]) ,
    ]);
```

it's error:

> Object of class yii\db\Query could not be converted to string

and when change main query to :

```
andWhere(['in', 'user_id', $q->select(["GROUP_CONCAT(user_id SEPARATOR ',')"])->from('damages')->where(['server_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])])
```

output is nothing.

How to solved this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can fire direct Query

```
$projceCities = Client::findBySql('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(c_state_id)) as c_state_id FROM `ls_client`')
    ->asArray()
    ->one();
```

Result will be like

```
Array
(
    [c_state_id] => 6,10,3,22,2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

for andWhere you can use literal where

```
$q = new Query();
  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => Ticket::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
          ->andWhere(" user_id in (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`user_id` SEPARATOR ',') FROM damages where server_id = " . 
                            Yii::$app->user->identity->id . ");") ,
  ]);
```

but looking at your code could be you need

```
$q = new Query();
  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => Ticket::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
          ->andWhere(" user_id in (SELECT `user_id`  FROM damages where server_id = " . Yii::$app->user->identity->id . ");") ,
  ]);
```

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';)'

Comment: I removed ' ; '   but output is nothing again.

Comment: could is the group concat that create  problem   ... i have update the asnwer with a suggestion .. let me know anyway seems the teh error you signed in you question don't appear ..